# Format HTML prior to serving the page

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using ASP.NET-MVC, and would like to format my html prior to sending it to the browser.

I have one page with multiple partialviews, and i want it all to be indented nicely.

I know this is stupid, but while in development it's nice to have well formatted html when you go: RightClick -> View Source.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this blog post:
[ASP.NET MVC clean HTML](http://blog.aquabirdconsulting.com/?p=61)

I think it's exactly what you're looking for. The author uses `ActionFilter`s and [Tidy.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tidynet/) to format the HTML output.

Comment: This is 100% spot on, thanx a million

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is possible - it certainly does not seem practical - it would be a lot of formatting work on every page when you will only occasionally use view source.

I would suggest selecting a different text editor to do your view source, and then use the editor's formatting tools to format the html. I use [TextPad](http://www.textpad.com/) and while the html formatting isn't fabulous, it does help. I am sure there are other editors you could try for this.

Comment: i am loading partial views.. so code blocks sits in different pages

Comment: sure, but when it all comes down to the browser, and you do 'view source' - it is all in on place

Comment: in place yes, formatted no. DAve's answer is exactly what i wanted. thanx

Comment: I'm glad you found what you need - my suggestion was to format after the fact - rather than format every page that the server serves, you can format -after- you do the 'view source' - you get what you need without the server load

Comment: i follow :) ... and it is more practical to install a text viewer, i subsiquintly installed TextPad, thanx for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, there the [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net)/[JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) is for. There are ports available in [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) and [ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289176%28VS.71%29.aspx) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can either inject code that gets executed every single request, with attendant risks or overhead. Or you could [get better tools](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/697/).